# How can I fix a page not found error in my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 3.0 app.

In it I have a view called Management, living in /Views/Home.

I also have a controller called ManagementController.cs, and a method like this:

```
 public IActionResult Management()
    {
        return View("Views/Home/Management");
    }
```

In startup.cs, there is this code block:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");


            endpoints.MapRazorPages(); 
        });
```

However, I cannot seem to browse to this page (404). What am I missing?

Comment: If the controller is called ManagementController, then you should have a view folder called Management and inside the folder, the views bound to the controller.

Comment: /Views/Home should contain the views for the Home controller and the views for the ManagementController should be in /Views/Management folder

Answer (score 0):

You are missing file suffix, change your action to:

```
public IActionResult Management()
    {
        return View("Views/Home/Management.cshtml");
    }
```